# Meteor Collections that expire

Tags: meteor

I would like to set a session bound value that's synced between client and server in Meteor. I'm thinking that should be done in a Collection, since Session isn't synced between client and server, right? It's important that the data is cleared after a certain amount of time though, since it's actually base64 encoded images I'm looking to store.

Is it possible to set an expiration date for a Meteor Collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend indexing the particular field in the collection with a TTL parameter, this will ensure that documents expire after a specified time.

Do it from the Mongo shell like so:

```
db.myCollection.ensureIndex( { "fieldName": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

Answer (score 3):

You could remove the records for a collection after a certain amount of time.

**Server side code:**

```
//Run every minute
Meteor.setInterval(function() {

    MyCollection.remove({expires: { $gte: new Date() }});

}, 60000);
```

When you insert it you can set an expiry:

**Server side code:**

```
MyCollection.deny({
    insert: function(userId, doc) {
        //Set expiry to 24 hours from now
        doc.expires = new Date( new Date().getTime() + (36000000*24) );

    }
});
```

The deny method adds the expiry time on the server, even if you add a document from the client. This way you can ensure documents expire regardless of the time on the client, which can often be incorrect.

Then you can insert the document on the client side

**Client side**

```
MyCollection.insert({ base64data: xxxxxx });
```

Also yes you're right, `Session` does not sync with the server.

Comment: Well-written answer and good solution, but since MongoDB apparently provides native support, I'll mark @KyleSA's answer as correct.